# How to allow applications to clear their uncollectable types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, garbage-collection

In the Python 3 documentation for [gc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html), a piece of information under `gc.callbacks` reads:

> Applications can add their own callbacks to this list. The primary use cases are: [...]
>
> Allowing applications to identify and clear their own uncollectable types when they appear in garbage.

It doesn't provide information on clearing. As far as I know, there is no function in Python to manually free memory. And even if there was, the general consensus I've observed online concerning the garbage collector is, don't mess with it.

If there was uncollectable garbage present in `gc.garbage`, how do you ensure that it's collected when `gc.collect` is called?